# Weighted sum smaller than given interpolated value between minimum and maximum

Tags: linear-algebra

This concerns a small step I found in a proof of another theorem. Since it was not really proved there but just stated I guess it should be rather obvious but I tried several ways of proving this, and I could not find a correct proof for it. What am I not seeing?

It concerns a weighted sum.

Suppose $\{x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n\}$ are all positive numbers, and $\{w_1,w_2,\ldots,w_n\}$ are the corresponding weights, those are also positive: $0<w_i<1$ and satify $\sum_{i=1}^n w_i = 1$.

Next we define the weighted sum: $W=\sum_{i=1}^n w_ix_i$

If we call $x_{max} = \max (x_1,x_2,\dots ,x_n)$ and $x_{min} = \min (x_1,x_2,\dots ,x_n)$ and $s$ is a positive numbers that is smaller than all the weights: $0 <s \leq w_i, 1\leq i\leq n$.

Then is was stated that
$$W \leq s x_{min} + (1-s) x_{max}$$

It is easy to show that
$$x_{min} \leq W \leq x_{max}$$
where equality will only hold when the weights in the weighted sum $\sum_{i=1}^n w_ix_i$ are all zero apart from one 1 at $x_{min}$ or $x_{max}$. Since we asked that all the weights should be positive, the equality will never hold:
$$x_{min} < W < x_{max}$$

By interpolating between $x_{min}$ and $x_{max}$:
$$f(t)=tx_{min} + (1-t)x_{max}$$
we get all the values between $x_{max}$ and $x_{min}$. By chosing $t$ small enough ($t_s\leq\frac{x_{max} - W}{x_{max} - x_{min}}$) we can make sure that the interpolation results in a value between $W$ and $x_{max}$, which is kind of what we want: $W\leq f(t_s) \Leftrightarrow W \leq t_s x_{min} + (1-t_s) x_{max}$.

But I don't seem to be able to correlate this $t_s$ with the given value of $s$ to prove the former inequality from that.

Any hints would be appreciated.

Thanks a lot, Jan.

Comment: Note that "where equality will only hold when the weights in the weighted sum $\sum_{i=1}^n w_ix_i$ are all zero apart from one 1 at $x_{min}$ or $x_{max}$." is not true. Equality also hold when all $x_i$ are the same, or when several $x_i = x_\min$ and the sum of their weights is 1, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is simpler than what you made of it. Lets "turn" all weights into $x_{\max}$ apart from $x_{\min}$'s weight - we of course increased the value.
$$
W = \sum w_i x_i = w_{\min} x_{\min}+\sum_{i\ne \min}w_ix_i\le w_{\min}x_{\min}+(1-w_{\min})x_{\max}
$$
where the last inequality follows from the fact that the weights sum to $1$.

Now, since $s < w_{\min}$, then $sx_{\min} + (1-s)x_{\max}$ is of course larger, because you "move weight" from a smaller number to a larger number. Thus,
$$ W \le sx_{\min} + (1-s)x_{\max}$$

Comment: To make the conclusion more obvious, you can restate the last paragraph: $x_{max}-w_{min}\cdot\left(x_{max}-x_{min}\right)\leq x_{max}-s\cdot\left(x_{max}-x_{min}\right)$

Comment: Thank you very much Amir. This is indeed al lot simpler and more elegant.

Comment: @RezhaAdrianTanuharja, of course algebraically you are right, but I like to emphasize this inequality in a much more intuitive manner (as it is intuitive), which the algebra misses in my opinion.